# In Spring 3 is it possible to dynamically set the reason of @ResponseStatus?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a custom exception class annotated to return a given `HttpStatus`:

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Invalid parameter")
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException
{
  public BadRequestException(String msg)
  {
    super(msg);
  }
}
```

This works when I throw a `BadRequestException` from my controller but the reason is always "Invalid parameter" of course.  Is there a way to set the returned reason in this class?  I'd like to pass a string to be used as the reason.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `HttpServletResponse`'s `sendError` function to achieve that.
Here is an example of how to use it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "some/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doAction(final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
  response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "custom error message");
}
```

Comment: what is response?

Comment: @user3871754, `response` can be obtained in the controller method.  What @Bozho's saying is that instead of throwing an exception in my controller method I should instead call `response.sendError`.

Answer (score 23):

If you omit the 'reason' attribute in the @ResponseStatus annotation on a custom exception,

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONFLICT)  // 409
public class ChildDataExists extends RuntimeException {
...
```

then throw the exception - in your *service* layer.  Thus you don't need a catch and throw something else or catch in the controller to set the response directly to some HTTP status code.

```
throw new ChildDataExists("Can't delete parent if child row exists.");
```

The exception's message comes through as the 'message' of the 'data' in the JSON output. It seems the 'reason' in the annotation overrides the custom behavior.  So you can have say one basic exception for a given context and use it in a dozen places, each with a slightly differing message where it is thrown and all get's handled properly out to the REST interface.

Comment: Huh, it seems I've used this feature few times without knowing it. Thanks!

Comment: Did not work for me. I set the status code to BAD_REQUEST (400) but got 'Bad request' as both the error and the message fields. Even if the exceptions message was set in my exception object.

Comment: This works great. Thank you. This is so much easier then having special catches to throw errors.

Comment: this really was an eye-opener :)

Comment: Message is still blank.

Comment: If message is blank, setting `server.error.include-message=always` in the application.properties file can help.

Comment: This answer is old, but I updated it to show you can throw it from the service layer not just the controller.  Perhaps this answers your question @AndreasPresthammer along with the config that @ cesarse notes. My answer was specifcally trying to avoid manually setting the status code like esponse.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), .....

Comment: As a note, I do not send error messages in the Controller directly.  I use a specific class called RestExceptionAdvice that is annotated with @ControllerAdvice.  It transposes all exceptions caught to JSON marshaled messages etc with the correct HTTP status code to my exception.   Ie AppNotFoundException is always marshaled to a message with a 404.

Answer (score 12):

The correct way is to introduce exception handler in your controller, then you can set response body of any status code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SomeController {
...
  @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  public @ResponseBody
   Map<String,Object> handleIndexNotFoundException(BadRequestException bre,
                                           HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {
     HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
     result.put("error", true);
     result.put("error_message", bre.getMessage());
     return result;
  }
}
```

Move over you don't have to pollute your model/exception classes with any Spring Web MVC annotations and dependency.

If you want to share the handler with all controller look into [@ControllerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html).

Comment: Question was about setting reason phrase, not body.

Answer (score 7):

Since spring 5.0, you can use the `ResponseStatusException` which is available

> ```
> // From https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception
> @GetMapping("/actor/{id}")
> public String getActorName(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
>     try {
>         return actorService.getActor(id);
>     } catch (ActorNotFoundException ex) {
>         throw new ResponseStatusException(
>           HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "Actor Not Found", ex);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are meant to be static, and can't be set dynamically from your class.  I suggest creating a subclass of your `BadRequestException` for every type of failure scenario and annotating them differently.

This doesn't just serve as a workaround -- if you're hiding the details regarding what went wrong in the `reason` message, then you're losing flexibility because any code that catches a `BadRequestException` will have to deal with all failure scenarios the same way.

Comment: In this case the code that ultimately deals with the exception has to deal with it in the same way...the controller is responding to an asynchronous request from a JavaScript front end. On any

Comment: I see what you mean.  I would still argue that it's good design with no harm (other than introducing a few more Exception classes than you already have), but if you're inclined to try to go a different route, the method Bozho mentioned and/or the one described here might be useful: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100267-Changing-ResponseStatus-from-within-controller-method .  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to just set the `response.setStatus()`. Easy and clean, you can change it to any status you want just instead of `ex.getStatusCode()` add your code.

The return type is also of your choice, I'm using String b/c displaying this later.

By the way, the `sendError` is not a good idea, because JBoss for instance is adding a lot of HTML to the response.

```
@ExceptionHandler(CommunicationException.class)
@ResponseBody()
public String handleCommunicationException(CommunicationException ex, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
    response.setStatus(ex.getStatusCode());
    return ex.getStatusMessage();   
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The "reason" is optional, so you can omit that and implements the abstract method public  String reason passing the Error.
Link: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseStatus.html

Comment: What do you mean by *"and implements the abstract method public String reason passing the Error"*? I don't think just adding a `reason` or `getReason` method to the OP's `public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException` would allow one to dynamically set a message?