# Throwing a HTTPMessageConverter with Autowired Text Processor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to create a RuntimeException with set up HTTP Status and Text. There is a textService which creates the text.

I read so many threads, but still don't get it.

I can't used the autowired textService in the constructor like this:

```
    @Autowired
    public myException(String param) {
        this.param = ts.getMsg(param);
    }
```

because in construction time I don't have the autorwired object. That's quite understandable. In some threads I read I should overwrite the getMessage function which seems quite logic to me and results in the following:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
public class myException extends RuntimeException {

    @Autowired
    private transient textService ts;

    private String param = "default";

    public myException(String param) {
        this.param = param;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return ts.getMsg(param);
    }

}
```

But when throwing it

```
throw new myException("foo");
```

I get a Errorpage with correct Status but no text.

This is happening not in a controller but in a HTTPMessageConverter btw., so I don't can access the response Object directly.

Using Spring WebMVC 4.3.4.RELEASE.

Other Ideas I had (but didn't figure out working):

- Throwing a new Exception in a @PostContruct-Method
- Somehow access the reason-annotation of the class

Threads I read (and lots more)

- [How to set my own message in my custom exception in Java that can be retrieved my getMessage() BUT WITHOUT using the constructor, is there any way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313084/how-to-set-my-own-message-in-my-custom-exception-in-java-that-can-be-retrieved-my)
- [Spring passsing autowired object to class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29012714/spring-passsing-autowired-object-to-class-constructor)
- [how to set message to a custom exception class without setting through super constructor in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216478/how-to-set-message-to-a-custom-exception-class-without-setting-through-super-con)
- [In Spring 3 is it possible to dynamically set the reason of @ResponseStatus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594645/in-spring-3-is-it-possible-to-dynamically-set-the-reason-of-responsestatus)
- [Dynamic message for custom exception annotated as ResponseStatus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836689/dynamic-message-for-custom-exception-annotated-as-responsestatus)

Most likely the solution is somewhere but I am obviously blind so maybe some friendly person might open my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@ControllerAdvice` coupled with `@ExceptionHandler`.

e.g.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerClass {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    @ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException me) {
        return new ResponseEntity(me.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

}
```

Comment: So this is meant to be a second class I have to define?

Comment: You could or you can write the exception handler method in you controller only.i.e. you can add this code to your controller and it will work. @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
@ExceptionHandler(myException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> handlerMyException(myException me) {
    return new ResponseEntity(me.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}

Comment: That Worked! I also removed all @ResponseStatus-annotations  since the response status is set in the code.

Comment: Glad to help you !